# Link between HTML and CSS not functioning

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

hr {
  border-style: none;
  border-top-style: dotted;
  border-color: #12947f;
  border-width: 4px;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Donald's Personal Site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I am new to coding and I've spent three days trying to figure out what was wrong with my page. Could someone please help me to resolve this issue, so that I can continue to improve on my coding?

Comment: What indication of a problem are you observing?  What specifically doesn't work?

Comment: for some reason the link does not work, the background color of my page never changes

Comment: along with the other pieces of code

Comment: Is your CSS in the file that you're referencing?  Open your browser's debugging tools (F12 in Chrome) and reload the page, observing the requests made in the Network tab.  There should be a request for the `style.css` file.  What is the result of that request?

Comment: The href seems be incorrect.Write in the form of href="~/FolderName/css/style.css". This is called Relative path.

Comment: @noobprogrammer  : i tried that and still nothing

Comment: @ david: the netwrok tab says that it failed to load the style

Comment: Have you specified the body yet? I am pretty sure if there is no`<body>` tag, then the `<body>` background can't be changed. If not, make sure to see if the file location is set. If you are in a folder, with `index.html`, and the `href="css/style.css"`, then that means that in the current folder there is another folder name `css`, and in that, there is a file called style.css. If not, try changing that. Also specify that the link `type="text/css"` as that is commonly found in `<link />` tags.

Comment: @TheBEEF: *"the netwrok tab says that it failed to load the style"* - What specifically and exactly does it say?  What is the HTTP response code?  404?

Comment: @ jason d'silva : ok i will try that

Comment: @ david: index.html:6 GET file:///C:/Users/Donald%20Stewart/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.47.0/Web%20Development%20DAS/HTML%20-%20Personal%20Site/~/css/css/style.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: this is what i see, i do not see anything else

Comment: @TheBEEF: File not found means exactly that, it's not found.  Why is there a `~` in the path?  That's not in the code you're showing.  The repeated `css` folder name is also suspect.  What is the current URL of the page in the browser when you get this error?

Comment: @TheBEEF Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code **misses some HTML tags**
You never declared **body, hr** tags in your HTML doc file and trying to modify them in CSS sheet. It doesn't make any sense.
Here I fixed your mistakes, Have a look

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Donald's Personal Site</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        </head>

       <body>
           <hr>
       </body>
   </html>
```

Also, make sure href to CSS file is right.

Answer (score 0):

Some reasons why your code isn't working:

1. **Wrong path:** if your path in href attribute is incorrect then it won't work.

***Fix:*** make sure your path is correct, this is done by referencing the folder or directory where your CSS file is located.
To simply debug this as a beginner still learning paths and directory linking, put your CSS file in root directory and simply link to it by this:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

2. **Wrong spelling:** you may have spelt the CSS file name wrongly in href.

**Fix:** crosscheck the filename and correct spelling in href

3. Maybe adding type attribute to your code might help for reasons i have limited knowledge of, so try adding type attribute.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/style.css">
   ```